# How to sanitize for SQL injection

Tags: string, pdo, sanitization

I'm stuck on how to sanitize the code below for SQL injections.

Line 3 is where I'm stuck and put ??? for the value I'm not sure of. I'd also appreciate if someone can review the entire thing to check if I made other mistakes.

$path will look something like /1/A/2/B/3/C/

```
1 $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
2 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE path = :path");
3 $path = filter_input(???, 'path', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
4 $post->bindParam(':path', $path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
5 $post->execute();
```

Comment: @JohnConde Can you please show me where filter_input is used? I do not see it in the link provided.

Comment: Please read the linked question carefully and try to understand how SQL injection actually works. Blaming *dangerous* characters that get through is a common misconception.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario So filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'path', ..) wouldn't be correct? I'm not sure why the method linked is better than what I had written. I guess I'm having a hard time understanding something out of a PHP textbook vs someone's post on here.

Comment: You are not sure because you don't really understand what SQL injection is or how parametrised queries work. Learn that and you'll realise yourself. Seriously :)